# Download file from web with dynamic name using XPath of file link

Tags: powershell

I’ve been using a PowerShell script with `Invoke-WebRequest` to download a file from a website.  I now need to be able to get the file once a week, but the filename changes weekly, and therefore the URL does as well.

It appears the XPath of the link to the file within the HTML page remains static, so I have that as an option.

Assuming the URL to the page is `https://www.contoso.com/index.html` and the XPath locator to the file link is `//*[@id="element_id"]` how can I achieve this in my script using said XPath locator instead of the URL?

Comment: Are you using Windows PowerShell or PowerShell Core?

Comment: I have and use both.

Comment: You probably want to use `GetElementById("element_id")` rather than an XPath query.